# transforming pvclaims into configmaps using jq

Tags: json, kubernetes, deployment, jq

Here is my input:

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "spec": {
    "template": {
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "mountPath": "/var/www/html",
                "name": "shared"
              },
              {
                "mountPath": "/var/www/html/LocalSettings.d/LocalSettings.override.php",
                "name": "movies-wikibase-claim1"
              },
              {
                "mountPath": "/var/www/html/img/wikibase_logo.png",
                "name": "movies-wikibase-claim2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "shared",
            "persistentVolumeClaim": {
              "claimName": "shared"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "movies-wikibase-claim1",
            "persistentVolumeClaim": {
              "claimName": "movies-wikibase-claim1"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "movies-wikibase-claim2",
            "persistentVolumeClaim": {
              "claimName": "movies-wikibase-claim2"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to transform any mountpath ending with an extension into a mountPath pointing to a  corresponding 'configMaps' object that itself replaces the pre-existing associated 'persistentVolumeClaim'.

With this result:

```json
    {
    ...
                "volumeMounts": [
                  {
                    "mountPath": "/var/www/html",
                    "name": "shared"
                  },
                  {
                    "mountPath": "/var/www/html/LocalSettings.d/LocalSettings.override.php",
                    "name": "movies-wikibase-localsettings-override-php",
                    "subPath": "LocalSettings.override.php"
                  },
                  {
                    "mountPath": "/var/www/html/img/wikibase_logo.png",
                    "name": "movies-wikibase-wikibase-logo-png",
                    "subPath": "wikibase_logo.png"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "volumes": [
              {
                "name": "shared",
                "persistentVolumeClaim": {
                  "claimName": "shared"
                }
              },
              {
                "configMap": {
                  "defaultMode": 420,
                  "name": "movies-wikibase-localsettings-override-php"
                },
                "name": "movies-wikibase-localsettings-override-php"
              }
              {
                "configMap": {
                  "defaultMode": 420,
                  "name": "movies-wikibase-wikibase-logo-png"
                },
                "name": "movies-wikibase-wikibase-logo-png"
              }
```

I've begun some stuff, but I didn't manage to achieve it:

```
cat movies-wikibase-deployment.json| 
   jq -r '((.spec.template.spec.containers[].volumeMounts[]?|select(.mountPath|test("(\\.[^.]+)$")))|={mountPath: .mountPath, name: ((.name|split("-claim")|.[0]) + "-" + (.mountPath|split("/")|last|gsub("_";"-")|gsub("\\.";"-")|ascii_downcase)), subPath: (.mountPath|split("/")|last)})|(((.spec.template.spec.containers[].volumeMounts[]?|select(.mountPath|test("(\\.[^.]+)$")).name) ) as $toto|.spec.template.spec.volumes+=[{configMap: {defaultMode: 420, name: $toto}, name: $toto}])'
```

EDIT: In stead of one long line of code, you could have written a slightly more readable version like:

```
jq -r '(
         (.spec.template.spec.containers[].volumeMounts[]?|
          select(.mountPath|test("(\\.[^.]+)$")))|=
          {mountPath: .mountPath, name: ((.name|split("-claim")|.[0]) + "-" + (.mountPath|split("/")|last|gsub("_";"-")|gsub("\\.";"-")|ascii_downcase)), subPath: (.mountPath|split("/")|last)}
       )|
        (
         ((.spec.template.spec.containers[].volumeMounts[]?|select(.mountPath|test("(\\.[^.]+)$")).name) ) as $toto|
         .spec.template.spec.volumes+=[{configMap: {defaultMode: 420, name: $toto}, name: $toto}])'  movies-wikibase-deployment.json
```

Comment: it says that there is too much code, but the sample is ok

Comment: every solution sounds good to me, but I think I was not very far from the solution with jq, I am curious to see what I miss.

Comment: I added an EDIT, to "make the long command line more readable"   (but I am los about the _desired_ output....)

Comment: Hi, could you please put your question in from of the text. Not the example code? If someone is searching for an answer to their problem, they probably want to read the problem setting first to decide if that is what they are searching for, not a longish data example.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to modify array items in two distinct places and in two distinct ways, but all based on the same values that come from transforming the same source, I'd recommend setting up a lookup table (e.g. using `INDEX`), and then querying it in both cases (instead of recurring to the same source and repeating the same transformations over and over):

```bash
.spec.template.spec |= (

  INDEX(.containers[].volumeMounts[]
    | {id: .name, subPath: (.mountPath / "/")[-1]}
    | .name = (.id | .[:index("claim")])
            + (.subPath | gsub("[_.]";"-") | ascii_downcase);
    select(.subPath | test("[.][^.]+$")).id
  ) as $lookup
  
  # With the sample input, $lookup would contain:
  # 
  # {
  #   "movies-wikibase-claim1": {
  #     "id": "movies-wikibase-claim1",
  #     "subPath": "LocalSettings.override.php",
  #     "name": "movies-wikibase-localsettings-override-php"
  #   },
  #   "movies-wikibase-claim2": {
  #     "id": "movies-wikibase-claim2",
  #     "subPath": "wikibase_logo.png",
  #     "name": "movies-wikibase-wikibase-logo-png"
  #   }
  # }

  | .containers[].volumeMounts[] |= last(., {mountPath} + (
      $lookup[.name] | values | {name, subPath}
    ))

  | .volumes[] |= last(., (
      $lookup[.name] | values | {configMap: {defaultMode: 420, name}, name}
    ))

)
```

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "spec": {
    "template": {
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "mountPath": "/var/www/html",
                "name": "shared"
              },
              {
                "mountPath": "/var/www/html/LocalSettings.d/LocalSettings.override.php",
                "name": "movies-wikibase-localsettings-override-php",
                "subPath": "LocalSettings.override.php"
              },
              {
                "mountPath": "/var/www/html/img/wikibase_logo.png",
                "name": "movies-wikibase-wikibase-logo-png",
                "subPath": "wikibase_logo.png"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "shared",
            "persistentVolumeClaim": {
              "claimName": "shared"
            }
          },
          {
            "configMap": {
              "defaultMode": 420,
              "name": "movies-wikibase-localsettings-override-php"
            },
            "name": "movies-wikibase-localsettings-override-php"
          },
          {
            "configMap": {
              "defaultMode": 420,
              "name": "movies-wikibase-wikibase-logo-png"
            },
            "name": "movies-wikibase-wikibase-logo-png"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0kbYfmmJsbm)